# Finding the time at which the queue clears (basic traffic theory)

Tags: integration, derivatives

I have the following practise problem:

[image]

And the follow up question:

**determine the longest queue length (in vehicles).**

The arrival curve $A(t)$ can be found by integrating the arrival rate $\lambda(t)$. Same goes with the departure curve$D(t)$, just integrate the departure rate $\mu \left(t\right)$.

When the queues clears = when arrival curve intersect the departure curve.

The queue length is $Q(t) = A(t) - D(t)$, to find the maximum queue length, I need to take the derivative = 0. But I keep getting the wrong answer, so I suspect my $A(t)$ or $D(t)$ is wrong

Working:

Define $t$ as the time in minutes after 6:50 am.

$A\left(t\right)\:=\:\int \:\lambda \left(t\right)\:=\:\int \:2-0.04t\:=\:2t\:-\:0.02t^2$

$D\left(t\right)\:=\:\int \:\lambda \left(t\right)\:=\:\int \:4\:=\:4t$ (1 veh/15 secs = 4 vehs/minute)

But since departure starts later at 7:00am,$D(t) = 4(t-10)$

my working is wrong since I cannot find the correct answer to part 2. So where am I wrong? Which function is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your working looks OK. Once you have those integrals you want the number of accumulated vehicles to match the number of departed vehicles, so
$$
2t-0.02t^2=4(t-10)
$$
You should know how to rearrange that into a quadratic. It will make it easier if you multiply by 50. Then the solution to the quadratic will be $$(-100\pm\sqrt{18,000})/2,$$ and you obviously want the positive solution, which gives $\approx17$ minutes after 6:50, so the answer is indeed 7:07 as selected above.

Comment: Thanks. What about the second question? Finding the maximum queue length? I am getting the wrong answers.

Comment: You should show the working in the question.

Comment: Hi Suzu, I have included the $Q(t) = A(t) - D(t)$

Comment: Your A(t) and D(t) are both OK, what derivative did you get?

Comment: The problem is you get $t = -50$ as you answer when you solve derivative of Q(t) = 0. How can t be negative? So my a(t) and d(t) must be wrong

Comment: Please show the result you got by editing the question text.